# Borders in textInput in React-Native autocomplete-input

Tags: react-native, styles, border, expo, textinput

I'm trying to delete the top, right and left borders of my textInput (so obviously, I'd like to have just the bottom border :) ) with the package react-native-autocomplete-input

I tried borderTop : 0 / and  'transparent' but it's not working I still have the borders on top and sides.
borderStyle didn't work either

I get this: 
https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/03/ovck.bmp

my code is this:

```
  <ScrollView style={styles.containerScroll}>
      <Text style={styles.h1}>{i18n.t("tripsform.title")}</Text>
      <Autocomplete
        containerStyle={styles.container}
        inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        data={this.findAirports(query_arrival)}
        defaultValue={this.findAirports(query_start)}
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query_start: text })}
        placeholder="Enter Start airports"
        renderItem={({ airport }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.setState({ query_start: airport })}
          >
            <Text style={styles.h2}>{airport}-</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
      <Autocomplete
        containerStyle={styles.container}
        inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        data={this.findAirports(query_arrival)}
        defaultValue={this.findAirports(query_arrival)}
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query_arrival: text })}
        placeholder="Enter Arrival airports"
        renderItem={({ airport }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.setState({ query_arrival: airport })}
          >
            <Text style={styles.h2}>{airport}-</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
      <Form ref={c => (this._form = c)} type={Trip} options={options} />
      <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
      <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
      <Button
        containerStyle={[styles.mybtnContainer]}
        style={styles.mybtn}
        onPress={this.handleSubmit}
      >
        {i18n.t("tripsform.item.add").toUpperCase()}
      </Button>
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("MyTrips")}
        containerStyle={[styles.mybtnContainer]}
        style={styles.mybtn}
      >
        Return to my trips
      </Button>
      <Text>
        {"\n"}
        {"\n"}
      </Text>
    </ScrollView>
```

with this style:

```
inputContainer: {
minWidth: 300,
width: "90%",
height: 55,
backgroundColor: "transparent",
color: "#6C6363",
fontSize: 18,
fontFamily: "Roboto",
borderBottomWidth: 1,
borderBottomColor: "rgba(108, 99, 99, .7)"
},
```

If I can get any help that's really nice, thanks for reading and for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's impossible with that package.

I could do what I wanted to do with 'native base autocomplete'.
So, it doesn't completely answer the question but it allows you to do the right thing!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `inputContainerStyle` property to apply styles to the input.

You can also use `containerStyle` to style the container around the AutoComplete so you also don't need to wrap the `Autocomplete` with `View` tag.

```js
<Autocomplete
  inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I try what you advise me but If I do, I have this : https://zupimages.net/up/20/03/4dda.bmp

Comment: remove the `padding: 5` from your style, or it may be your `View` wrapped around the input, you could also try messing with `containerStyle`

Comment: Alright, thanks i removed also borderStyle : 'dashed' but still : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/03/ovck.bmp

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `inputContainer` style `borderWidth` to 0:

```css
    // other styles
    inputContainer: {
        borderWidth: 0,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should give you the desired output :) :

```
<Autocomplete
   inputContainerStyle={{width:"100%",borderBottomWidth:1}}
   inputStyle={{borderWidth:0}}
   data={Options}
   handleSelectItem={(item,id)=>optionHandler(item.value,id)}
   valueExtractor={item => item.value}
  />
```